# input boxes, when on click on specified input box, the current pointer jump from the previous input box

Tags: html, css

I have input boxes, now the problem is, when i clicked one of any of the input boxes, the current pointer moves up or the current focus event has transferred or switch to another input box and its kinda odd. Im currently searching for the fix for this but unfortunately, found nothing so far.

for accurate details, below is supposedly a illustration.

i have three input boxes.

```
<input type="text" class="inputOne" value="" />
<input type="text" class="inputTwo" value="" />
<input type="text" class="inputThree" value="" />
```

and when I click 'inputTwo' for example, the cursor or pointer or the focus event of the clicked input box is transferred or switch to the 'inputOne', thus, i have to use tab all the way to be able get back to the specified input box.

Comment: That is a really odd issue. You're going to need to provide background information.

Comment: Do you have any other code in your file/program, some Javascript? It really looks like this shouldn't be happening.